# Execute javaScript in UIWebView in Swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift3, uiwebview

I am trying to execute the Amazon Mobile Add in my iOS application using Swift 3.0.  The file loads successfully.  I can run the google URL (code commented below) in the webView.  I don't understand how to execute the  javaScript.  I have been reading tutorials, but nothing seems to run the script as-is natively in the webView.  I tried the webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript and the context.evaluateScript, but all I get is "Amazon Ad" and not the script output in the webView.

My question is, how do I run javaScript  in the simplest way in a webView - or any other view for that matter.  xxxxx are "redacted" user keys.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Amazon Ad</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
amzn_assoc_placement = "xxxxxx";
amzn_assoc_search_bar = "true";
amzn_assoc_tracking_id = "xxxxxx";
amzn_assoc_search_bar_position = "bottom";
amzn_assoc_ad_mode = "search";
amzn_assoc_ad_type = "smart";
amzn_assoc_marketplace = "amazon";
amzn_assoc_region = "US";
amzn_assoc_title = "Star Wars Black Series 6\"";
amzn_assoc_default_search_phrase = "Star Wars Black Series 6 Inch";
amzn_assoc_default_category = "All";
amzn_assoc_linkid = "xxxxxxx";
</script>
<script src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the UIViewController with UIWebView.  I tried both of the following,

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: common), 
webView.loadHTMLString(common, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
```

Code

```
import UIKit
import JavaScriptCore

class AmazonFullAdViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

var url = URL(string: "https://google.com")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webView.delegate = self

    // 1
    guard let commonJSPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "common", ofType: "js") else {
        //commonJSPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Series", ofType: "txt") else {
            print("Unable to read resource files.")
            return
    }

    // 2
    do {
        let common = try String(contentsOfFile: commonJSPath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        _ = context?.evaluateScript(common)
        // webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: common)
        webView.loadHTMLString(common, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
    } catch (let error) {
        print("Error while processing script file: \(error)")
    }

    //load initial URL
//        let req = URLRequest(url : url!)
//        webView.scalesPageToFit = true
//        webView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
//        webView.loadRequest(req)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to tell to `webview` that it needs load a html value, because your file is a html with javascript inside.

`self.webview.loadHTMLString(yourfile)`

Comment: I enveloped the javascript code in <html><body> tags.  If I run the html in a browser, it connects and runs fine.  When I use webView.loadHTMLString(common, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL) nothing renders in the web view.  The code call the delegate - func webViewDidFinishLoad